# pandas and statsmodels.ols formula api

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

If I have a formula as follows:

```
formula='Price ~ Age + Size + C(Color) + C(Type)'
```

Where Price,Age, and Size are continuous variables and Color and Type are categorical. If I am loading a dataframe (df) with a column for each variable and selecting the column for 'type' as follows:

```
types = set(df['type'])

Returned >> ['Cat','Dog','Rabbit','Mouse']
```

When I go to perform the regression like this:

```
y,X = dmatrices(formula,df)
model = statsmodels.OLS(y,X)
mdl = model.fit()
mdl.summary()
```

I go to look for the parameters for each variable and find that there is not a variable included in the summary for some of the categorical values of the dummy variable placed in the model...for example 'T.Cat' is missing...any idea what is going on here? It is especially alarming because the categorical value usually missing (ie. without a tuned parameter) is typically the most common value....

Comment: When you use categorical variables with k number of classes, you only need k-1 dummy variables. The regression returns the result for a cat when dog, rabbit and mouse all = 0. It can't be anything other than a cat if it's none of the other 3. The coefficients for dog, rabbit and mouse tell you the expected change in price when all else is equal but you are changing from a cat to a dog etc. I'm pretty sure there's a way to change which class is the base case, but I'm too lazy to look it up.

Comment: see also http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/contrasts.html and http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/contrasts.html